# Login page is displayed when I refresh Homepage in React with Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I implemented Firebase authentication in my app by the docs. I have a login screen and a landing screen which is accessed only if you are logged in.

For some reason, when I am logged in and I refresh my landing screen, it redirects me to login screen and then back to the landing screen. I'm having a hard time figuring out why.

Here is some code that could help you out:

`index.js` (imports and other stuff is left out)

```
root.render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <Router>
      <Toaster />
      <AppRouter />
    </Router>    
  </AuthProvider>    
);
```

`AuthProvider.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { FirebaseAuth } from "./firebase/config";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth, user => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user)
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null)
      }
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And here is the `AppRouter.js`

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import Landing from "./screens/Landing"
import {
  Navigate,
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./screens/auth/Login";
import { AuthContext } from './AuthProvider';

const AppRouter = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={!!currentUser ? <Landing /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
        exact
      />
      <Route
        path="/login"
        element={!currentUser ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/" />}
        exact
      />
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial `currentUser` state matches the confirmed "unauthenticated" user state, e.g. `null`. When the app mounts, this initial falsey value will be used when rendering the routes.

Use an initial `currentUser` state value that is neither "authenticated" nor "unauthenticated" and do an explicit check for this and conditionally return early so the app neither renders the protected content nor the redirect.

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth, user => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (currentUser === undefined) {
    return null; // <-- or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={!!currentUser ? <Landing /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
      />
      <Route
        path="/login"
        element={!currentUser ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/" />}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

For a more conventional method of implementing route protection see my answer [here](/a/66289280/8690857).